# How to Get the table name in database with select box?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

Recently,I'm creating a school library Ser with three table in database(Newlibrary).
Three table is - Econ books , Geo books ,Chem books 
In each table, it have (Student name) and (Tel No.).
I want to create a poor search engine with( A drop down list - Use select table) and input (Tel in
which selected table)
Here is the code ,How to use A drop down list to select table( Econ books or  Geo books or Chem books )and input tel to search in table which selected at the same time ?

((index.html))

```
    <form method="GET" action="searchtitle">
          <select name="booktype" value="<?=$['booktype']?>">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="a">Econbooks</option>
  <option value="b">Geobooks</option>
  <option value="c">Chembooks</option>
            </select>

    <input id="inputkeyword" type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Please enter a keyword...."/>
    <input type="submit" class="keyword" value="search" />  
</form>
```

((searchtitle.php))

```
    <?php

      $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
      mysql_select_db("newlibrary");

      $sql = "Select * from borrower
      where  Telp='$keyword' ";

      $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);


      if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 0)  {echo "<h1>No Record Has Been Found!!</h1> ";} else { 

  echo "<table id='borrowertable'  >
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
    </tr>" ;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

    $bid = $row[0];
       $Names = $row[1];
   $Tel = $row[2];


    echo "  <tr>
            <td>$bid</td>
            <td>$Names</td>
            <td>$Tel</td>
        </tr>";

        } 

 }

    mysql_close($con);
   echo "<p> <a href='index'>Back Home</a> ";
  ?>
```

How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to be able to search one of the three table as per user's selection using a phone number. I am not sure if you want to use Javascript, hope this can be helpful

First you need to pass both the Select and textbox values to searchtitle.php

```
function get_User() {

var user_data = {};
user_data['Book'] = document.getElementById("DropDownID").value; // get dropdown selected value
user_data['phone'] = document.getElementById("inputkeywor").value; // get dropdown selected value


$.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "searchtitle.php",

    beforeSend: function () {

    $( "#LoadingDiv" ).html("Searching User...");

    },

    data: user_data,

    success: function (data) {

    Here Data is the result of searchTtitle.php.....


    }}});
```

Then on `searchtitle.php` you get the values from

```
  $keyword = $_POST['phone'];
  $TableToQuery = $_POST['Book'];
```

call get_User on submit

```
 <input type="button" class="keyword" value="search" onclick="get_User()" />
```